# XML : Add new field with file URL

Tags: xml, xslt, solr, xquery, dataimporthandler

I have input file named myfile.xml with below content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file-format>
<data-set xfer="1.2.840.10008.1.2.1" name="Little Endian Explicit">
<element tag="0008,0018" vr="UI" vm="1" len="64" name="SOPInstanceUID">123</element>
</data-set>
</file-format>
```

I want to add a field named fileURL and its values should be path of my xml with .xml replaced with .jpg
I want an output file with below content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file-format>
<data-set xfer="1.2.840.10008.1.2.1" name="Little Endian Explicit">
<element tag="0008,0018" vr="UI" vm="1" len="64" name="SOPInstanceUID">123</element>
<element name="fileURL">/user/local/myfile.jpg</element>
</data-set>
</file-format>
```

Purpose for this is so that I can input this file to solr and use this URL for indexing later.
What is best way to do it?

Comment: Is it a static file? Or does the filename change from xml file to xml file?

Comment: I have multiple file stored in a directory. There are pairs of xml file and jpg files with same name. For example there is myfile.xml and myfile.jpg. I wan to add URL for jpg file in its corresponding xml file for all the files.

Comment: So it should be possible to do this with a xsl transformation that adds the element and replaces the file extension.

Comment: If you can use xslt 2.0, you could possibly make use `base-uri` to get the XML file name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648703/get-file-name-of-xml-file-with-xsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XSLT this code help you by replace function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="self-url" select="replace(base-uri(.), '.xml$', '.jpg')"/>
        <element name="{$self-url}"><xsl:value-of select="$self-url"/></element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```